# Google AdMob App Open Ad shows "Open app Flood"

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've implemented new AdMob ad type following manual here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-open-ads

```swift
        let request = GADRequest()
        GADAppOpenAd.load(
            withAdUnitID: adId,
            request: request,
            orientation: .portrait,
            completionHandler: { ad, error in
                if let ad = ad,
                   let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
                {
                    ad.present(fromRootViewController: vc)
                }
            }
        )
```

Ad is shown, but top label shows "Open app Flood" instead of my application[image]

How to change label and icon to my app?

Comment: If your app is not live on App store, it will show this.
If app is live, your app name and icon will be there. 

same thing happens in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also problem
But when I upload App to AppStore Problem is solved

[image]